# Return 400 when i use kubernetes Deployment rollback API

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Sorry, maybe this is not a problem.
Post data as below to url 
http://$ip:8080/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/deployment-1/rollback
`{"kind":"Deployment","apiVersion":"extensions\/v1beta1","name":"deployment-1","updatedAnnotations":"1111","rollbackTo":{"revision":0}}`

return error:

`{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Deployment in version \"v1beta1\" cannot be handled as a DeploymentRollback: converting (v1beta1.Deployment) to (extensions.DeploymentRollback): UpdatedAnnotations not present in src","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}`

Is there anything wrong with my post data?
Another question: 
If a Deployment has two pods, there're two container in each of pod. I want update one container's image(use the url `http://$ip:8080/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/$deployment_name`). If i just change the first container's image, another container is gone! Is that right? It means that if I want update one containers' label or image I need define all the info of the containers which in the same pod?

Answer (score 0):

UpdatedAnnotations should be a `map[string]string`, so try something like:

```
{
    "kind":"Deployment",
    "apiVersion":"extensions\/v1beta1",
    "name":"deployment-1",
    "updatedAnnotations": {"label":"1111"},
    "rollbackTo":{"revision":0}
}
```

For your second question, you should be able to PATCH just the container image that you want to change. If you use PUT (or `kubectl apply`) you need to provide the full PodSpec, including the containers that you aren't changing.

Comment: Thanks for help! Seems the only thing different with your answer and mine is "updatedAnnotations" should be a map[string]string. I modified my data, but still the same problem. By the way my kubernetes version is 1.22, what about yours?

Comment: For the second question, I try it again(PHP code). PATCH just the container image which I want change. The other one is gone again! Is this a bug?

Comment: curl --request PATCH --header "Content-Type:application/merge-patch+json" http://$ip:8080/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/deployment-patch --data '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"mofang-web","image":"abc.com\/docker\/mofang-web-cc:stable"}]}}}}'

Comment: I had already figure this out.Post data like this :{
    "kind": "DeploymentRollback",       
    "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1", 
    "name": "node-46",                  
    "rollbackTo": {
        "revision": 3                   
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I found the second question's answer
Should use API like this :

```
curl --request PATCH --header "Content-Type:application/strategic-merge-patch+json" http://$ip:8080/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/deploymen‌​t-patch --data '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"mofang-web","image":"abc.co‌​m\/docker\/mofang-web-cc:stable"}]}}}}'
```

But I still don't understand the differences between this three method:

```
application/json-patch+json
application/merge-patch+json
application/strategic-merge-patch+json
```